# Ruby: How to convert a string to boolean

Tags: ruby, string, boolean, type-conversion

I have a value that will be one of four things: boolean true, boolean false, the string "true", or the string "false".  I want to convert the string to a boolean if it is a string, otherwise leave it unmodified.  In other words:

"true" should become true

"false" should become false

true should stay true

false should stay false

Comment: Does the result *have* to be one of the two values `true` or `false` or is it enough if the result is truthy or falsey? If the latter, then `false` is already falsey, and both `true` and `'true'` are truthy, so the only value for which the result is not already correct, is `'false'`: `if input == 'false' then true else input end` should do it.

Comment: That's a great comment Jorg, however I would assume that for some applications it is necessary to have the boolean value true or false and not just a value that is truthy or false.

Comment: Emery, if you need to return a boolean you could prepend @Jörg's expression with two "nots": `!!(if input == 'false' then true else input end)`. The second `!` converts the return value to a boolean that is the opposite of what you want; the first `!` then makes the correction. This " trick" has been around a long time. Not everyone is fond of it.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
def true?(obj)
  obj.to_s.downcase == "true"
end
```

Comment: Yes, @null, the to_s method converts boolean true or false to "true" or "false" and leaves the value unchanged if was originally a string.  Now we are certain to have either "true" or "false" as a string... and we just need to use == check if the string is equal to "true".  If it is then the original value was either true or "true".  If it is not then the original value was false, "false", or something totally unrelated.

Comment: Since the string may be upcased/titled, downcasing will ensure a match: `obj.to_s.downcase == 'true'`

Comment: Use `downcase!` and you'll allocate 1 less object.  `downcase` will duplicate the existing string.  When Frozen String Literals becomes a Ruby default option, this will matter less.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the answer to include the suggestion of downcase! as per the above comments.  It's less elegant to read, but if you aren't sure what variable types you're working with, more robustness is never bad.

Comment: This wont report an error if you feed it bad data, so it's not a great solution if you need any error handling

Comment: nice to ones wanting to use `downcase!`, try to microptimize it and break the feature!

Comment: For performance you can use `[obj].to_s.casecmp("true").zero?`

Comment: yeps, in case you use `downcase!`, then: `true?(false) : FrozenError (can't modify frozen String: "false")`

Answer (score 206):

If you use Rails 5, you can do `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)`.

In Rails 4.2, use  `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_user(value)`.

The behavior is slightly different, as in Rails 4.2, the true value and false values are checked. In Rails 5, only false values are checked - unless the values is nil or matches a false value, it is assumed to be true.  False values are the same in both versions: 

`FALSE_VALUES = [false, 0, "0", "f", "F", "false", "FALSE", "off", "OFF"]`

Rails 5 Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/boolean.rb

Comment: This is helpful, though I wish that the set of `FALSE_VALUES` in Rails also included "no".

Comment: @pjrebsch Fairly simple to patch in your app. Just add `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean::FALSE_VALUES << "no"` to an initializer.

Comment: note that `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)` is case sensitive...so 'False' will evaluate to true as will any other string except for 'false'. empty strings `''` default to nil, not false. ^^ valuable insight provided here by @thomasfedb on initializer customization

Comment: `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(nil)` also returns `nil`.

Comment: As of Rails 5.2.4 the method suggested by @thomasfedb  no longer works because `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean::FALSE_VALUES` is frozen.

Comment: @moveson of course you can always substitute `FALSE_VALUES += ["no"]`

Comment: @thomasfedb When I run `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean::FALSE_VALUES`. The result here is an error: `NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean::FALSE_VALUES`

Answer (score 40):

I've frequently used this pattern to extend the core behavior of Ruby to make it easier to deal with converting arbitrary data types to boolean values, which makes it really easy to deal with varying URL parameters, etc.

```
class String
  def to_boolean
    ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(self)
  end
end

class NilClass
  def to_boolean
    false
  end
end

class TrueClass
  def to_boolean
    true
  end

  def to_i
    1
  end
end

class FalseClass
  def to_boolean
    false
  end

  def to_i
    0
  end
end

class Integer
  def to_boolean
    to_s.to_boolean
  end
end
```

So let's say you have a parameter `foo` which can be:

- an integer (0 is false, all others are true)
- a true boolean (true/false)
- a string ("true", "false", "0", "1", "TRUE", "FALSE")
- nil

Instead of using a bunch of conditionals, you can just call `foo.to_boolean` and it will do the rest of the magic for you.

In Rails, I add this to an initializer named `core_ext.rb` in nearly all of my projects since this pattern is so common.

```
## EXAMPLES

nil.to_boolean     == false
true.to_boolean    == true
false.to_boolean   == false
0.to_boolean       == false
1.to_boolean       == true
99.to_boolean      == true
"true".to_boolean  == true
"foo".to_boolean   == true
"false".to_boolean == false
"TRUE".to_boolean  == true
"FALSE".to_boolean == false
"0".to_boolean     == false
"1".to_boolean     == true
true.to_i          == 1
false.to_i         == 0
```

Comment: what about 't' and 'f' 'T' & 'F', 'y' & 'n', 'Y' & 'N'?

Comment: This works too well, eg. Does "buy" begin with a "b"? `"buy"=~/b/ => 0`  But `("buy"=~/b/).to_boolean => false`

Answer (score 36):

**Working in Rails 5**

```
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('t')     # => true
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('true')  # => true
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(true)    # => true
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('1')     # => true
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('f')     # => false
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('0')     # => false
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('false') # => false
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(false)   # => false
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(nil)     # => nil
```

Comment: `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast("False")      # => true`
... Use to_s.downcase on your input is a good idea

Comment: Careful:
`ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('fals') # => true`
`ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast('falso') # => true`

Comment: @RicardoVillamil why would you need to test if "fals" or "falso" are booleans?

Answer (score 35):

Don't think too much:

```
bool_or_string.to_s == "true"
```

So,

```
"true".to_s == "true"   #true
"false".to_s == "true"  #false 
true.to_s == "true"     #true
false.to_s == "true"    #false
```

You could also add ".downcase," if you are worried about capital letters.

Comment: `nil.to_s == 'true'           #false`

Comment: @juliangonzalez: this was the fact I was missing in all of the other explanations - thank you.

Comment: `nil.to_s == 'false' # false`

Answer (score 18):

```
if value.to_s == 'true'
  true
elsif value.to_s == 'false'
  false
end
```

Comment: Else you will have to check if it's a type String and if yes then check if it is 'true' and if yes then return true. Why all that comparisons?

Comment: Your code as a one-liner `value.to_s == 'true' ? true : false`

Comment: The if / elsif / end is probably the most readable for a beginner.  The to_s is probably not actually needed when using the elsif statement, because it won't execute either block under "if" or "elsif" when the boolean value doesn't match to a string, and then the boolean will remain intact.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 : Never do that, it defeats the purpose of the conditional operator : `if true then true, if false then false` Guess what? You can completely remove it! `value.to_s == 'true' ? true : false` should just be `value.to_s == 'true'`

Comment: @EricDuminil absolutely agree, rookie error at the time.

Comment: Note that this answer will return nil when the value can't be converted while those one-liners will never fail and always return false unless the value is 'true'. Both are valid approaches and may be the right answer to different situations, but they are not the same.

Comment: I didn't get @EricDuminil objection, can someone explain it to in simple english? the only issue I'm catching with Sagar ternary if, is that its `false` is less strict than Archana..

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo the ternary operator doesn't do anything in this case. Try without, and compare the results.

Comment: @EricDuminil ooh lmao! yep that's for sure! ty

Comment: @iceツor just `value.to_s == 'true'`

Answer (score 13):

```
h = { "true"=>true, true=>true, "false"=>false, false=>false }

["true", true, "false", false].map { |e| h[e] }
  #=> [true, true, false, false]
```

Answer (score 11):

In a rails 5.1 app, I use this core extension built on top of `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean`. It is working perfectly for me when I deserialize boolean from JSON string.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Boolean.html

```
# app/lib/core_extensions/string.rb
module CoreExtensions
  module String
    def to_bool
      ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.deserialize(downcase.strip)
    end
  end
end
```

initialize core extensions

```
# config/initializers/core_extensions.rb
String.include CoreExtensions::String
```

rspec

```
# spec/lib/core_extensions/string_spec.rb
describe CoreExtensions::String do
  describe "#to_bool" do
    %w[0 f F false FALSE False off OFF Off].each do |falsey_string|
      it "converts #{falsey_string} to false" do
        expect(falsey_string.to_bool).to eq(false)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails I prefer using `ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.cast(value)` as mentioned in other answers here

But when I write plain Ruby lib. then I use a hack where  `JSON.parse` (standard Ruby library) will convert string "true" to `true` and "false" to `false`. E.g.:

```
require 'json'
azure_cli_response = `az group exists --name derrentest`  # => "true\n"
JSON.parse(azure_cli_response) # => true

azure_cli_response = `az group exists --name derrentesttt`  # => "false\n"
JSON.parse(azure_cli_response) # => false
```

Example from live application:

```
require 'json'
if JSON.parse(`az group exists --name derrentest`)
  `az group create --name derrentest --location uksouth`
end
```

> confirmed under Ruby 2.5.1

Answer (score 5):

I have a little hack for this one. `JSON.parse('false')` will return `false` and `JSON.parse('true')` will return true. But this doesn't work with `JSON.parse(true || false)`. So, if you use something like `JSON.parse(your_value.to_s)` it should achieve your goal in a simple but hacky way.

Answer (score 4):

A gem like https://rubygems.org/gems/to_bool can be used, but it can easily be written in one line using a regex or ternary.

regex example:

```
boolean = (var.to_s =~ /^true$/i) == 0
```

ternary example:

```
boolean = var.to_s.eql?('true') ? true : false
```

The advantage to the regex method is that regular expressions are flexible and can match a wide variety of patterns.  For example, if you suspect that var could be any of "True", "False", 'T', 'F', 't', or 'f', then you can modify the regex:

```
boolean = (var.to_s =~ /^[Tt].*$/i) == 0
```

Comment: Note: `\A`/`\z`  is start/end of string and `^`/`$` is start/end of line. So if `var == "true\nwhatevs"` then `boolean == true`.

Comment: This really helped me and I like `var.eql?('true') ? true : false` very much. Thanks!

Comment: @Christian keep in mind it has to be var.to_s.eql? not just var.eql? otherwise it won't convert a boolean true to string 'true'

Answer (score 4):

Although I like the hash approach (I've used it in the past for similar stuff), given that you only really care about matching truthy values - since - everything else is false - you can check for inclusion in an array:

```
value = [true, 'true'].include?(value)
```

or if other values could be deemed truthy:

```
value = [1, true, '1', 'true'].include?(value)
```

you'd have to do other stuff if your original `value` might be mixed case:

```
value = value.to_s.downcase == 'true'
```

but again, for your specific description of your problem, you could get away with that last example as your solution.

Answer (score 3):

In rails, I've previously done something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...

  private def bool_from(value)
    !!ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.type_cast_from_database(value)
  end
  helper_method :bool_from

  # ...
end
```

Which is nice if you're trying to match your boolean strings comparisons in the same manner as rails would for your database.

Answer (score 3):

Rubocop suggested format:

```rb
YOUR_VALUE.to_s.casecmp('true').zero?
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.42.0/RuboCop/Cop/Performance/Casecmp

Comment: I like this answer because it's a one-liner that handles all the cases which were stated in the original question, including capital vs lowercase T and F in the words "true" and "false".  Unlike a regex it will not handle "T" or "F" by itself.  The only detractor is that the usage of "zero?" might be confusing to people who aren't familiar with that method.

Answer (score 0):

Close to what is already posted, but without the redundant parameter:

```
class String
    def true?
        self.to_s.downcase == "true"
    end
end
```

usage:

```
do_stuff = "true"

if do_stuff.true?
    #do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This function works for any input:

```
def true?(value)
 ![false, 0, "0", "f", "F", "false", "FALSE", "off", "OFF"].include? value
end
```

then you have:

```
true?(param) #returns true or false
```

Answer (score -4):

You could just add `!!` before the variable:

```
!!test_string
```

Comment: Please make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785735/7733418 Also, ...

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Yeah this is interesting; I gave it an upvote because I have never used !! before and am glad to know about it.  I agree that an explanation as to why it works to meet the original question would be good.

Comment: `!!` combined with any string will be `true`, so this will not work. All strings (even empty strings) are truthy. `!!"true"` and `!!"false"` are both `true`