# ActiveRecord Returning Different Results on Variations of Same Boolean

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have been trying to retrieve an amount of Users based on a certain query. The problem that I have is that my results vary greatly depending on whether I use `false` or `"false"`. Here is my query below:

```
User.all
    .where.not(id:1)
    .where.not("lower(promo) = ?","promo")
    .where(created_at:7.months.ago..6.months.ago, auto_renew: false)
```

This returns a list of three users that do fit the query. But when I run the following:

```
User.all
    .where.not(id:1)
    .where.not("lower(promo) = ?","promo")
    .where(created_at:7.months.ago..6.months.ago, auto_renew: "false")
```

This returns one user that was not on the original list. The `auto_renew` value is supposed to be a boolean. Why is there a difference in what returns, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

Per request, here is my schema for `users`:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.boolean  "auto_renew",             default: true
  end
```

Comment: show us your schema for the `users` table please

Comment: Ok. See the edit.

Comment: I would argue that the string `"false"` is not `false`. Why are you surprised that queries with different conditions return different results?

Comment: Because all 4 users should satisfy either one query or the other. They are intermixed in both. They all have the exact same values.

Comment: which version of RoR and database are you using?

Comment: Look at your logs or `.to_sql` and figure out what the difference is between the generated queries.

Answer (score 4):

`false != "false"`. The first is a **boolean**, and the second is a **string**.

In 99% of scenarios, you should be using `false`, not `"false"`.

I'm not certain why those queries are returning different result sets; it probably depends on which rails/database engine/version you're using. If you want to see the difference between the two commands, try running:

```
User.where(.....).to_sql
```

If for some reason you need to programatically convert `"false"` to `false`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322375/1954610).

Comment: (*Technically*, `false` is the singleton instance of `FalseClass`; ruby doesn't have booleans. But that's not really important in the context of my answer....)

Comment: I ran `.to_sql` for each query and the different was that when I called `"false"` the query read **'false'**. When I ran the one that just called the boolean `false` it read it as **'f'**. Anyway, thanks for your help. I'll see how to go from here.

Comment: Trying to figure out a work-around. Is it possible to see if it satisfies either `false` OR `"false"` while still passing all those other variables?

Comment: @ርollιn Why are you passing in `"false"` in the first place? That sounds to me as though something else in your code is returning Strings instead of the correct data type. However, if you do have a *good* reason for needing to need String-->Boolean conversion, then I already provided you with a link to the solution above.

Comment: If you had read my question, you would see that it is because they return two completely different results. I am wondering how to merge them.

Comment: @ርollιn `auto_renew` is a boolean column. You should *only* be querying it with `true` or `false` (or possibly `nil`). Do not query it with `"false"`, and do not merge the result of `false` and `"false"`. What is the additional database record(s) that you get when querying with `"false"`?

Comment: ...But if you really wanted to do that (don't!), then you could do: `where(..., , auto_renew: [false, "false"])`.