# Rails convert string data received from front-end to Boolean in the backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a drop down menu from front end whose value are"true" and 
"false" as a string respectively.

```
  {label: 'No', value: 'false'},
  {label: 'Yes', value: 'true'}
```

They will be insert into a column type with Boolean type.

As you can see, it may be problematic because the type mismatch.

The error i got in the console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/my_forms.json 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

So is there a efficient  way so that once the data is received,it will l be converted into Boolean

I am using Postgresql for my DB and React for my front-end, if that helps.

Comment: `it may be problematic`... But is it in fact problematic?

Comment: it is, I am encountering an error while trying to save a form and i ran into an :unprocessable_entity error

Comment: Interesting. It would likely be helpful, then, to include the error trace, etc. with your question. BTW, you might find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228873/ruby-how-to-convert-a-string-to-boolean) helpful.

Comment: @jvillian I will try to put a byebug in between so i can get a trace of it.

Answer (score 1):

if it is effectively passed as a string, you could add a callback in your model to ensure the value is correctly transformed

For example :

```
class YourModel
  before_validation :format_field,
                    if: proc { |model|
                      model.your_field.is_a?(String)
                    }
  def format_field
    your_field = (your_field == "true")
  end
end
```

Or a before action on your controller :

```
before_action :format_problematic_field
def format_problematic_field
  return unless params[:your_field].is_a?(String)
  params[:your_field] = params[:your_field] == "true"
end
```