# How to compare boolean values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am comparing data types based on requirement.I have boolean return values as string "true" or "false".I need to compare actual value with expected values.I am using below code for comparing but it is not comparing.How to compare boolean values in rails?

```
   if expected_value.include? "DataType_Boolean"
    #   Check that the actual value should be either true or false.
    if expected_value.casecmp("true").zero? || expected_value.casecmp("false").zero?
      result = "Passed"
    end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: How to convert a string to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228873/ruby-how-to-convert-a-string-to-boolean)

Comment: ok Thanks.I tried below which didn't work.                                                            
 def true?(obj)
  obj.to_s == "true"
end

Comment: did i miss anything?

Comment: if expected_value.include? "DataType_Boolean"
        #   Check that the actual value should be either true or false.
        if true?expected_value
          result = "Passed"
        end

Comment: i have tried above code

Comment: Everything depends on your input `expected_value` and what you trying to achieve. As far as I understand, you want to `result = "Passed"` only when the `expected_value` contains `"true"` or `"false"`. Am I right?

Comment: yes correct Shemek

Comment: So why you do not use the simplest possible if: `if expected_value == "true" or expected_value == "false"`?

Comment: ok.But it is not taking ?. getting error

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ':'

Comment: Please replace your second `if` (whole line) with the one that I added in my last comment (without the question mark from the comment).

Comment: No.It is not working.Not updating result as passed or failed.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the examples of `expected_value` for both `true` and `false`?

Comment: Requirement is i need to execute some bulk parameters through api call and get results of those parameter and  compare actual datatype from api actual values to    expected value.expected value is available in database.  DataType_Boolean is one of the datatype condition which is  in database.

Comment: Can you please share all possible values `expected_value` can have?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `expected_value` looks something like this (and is not an array):

`"DataType_Boolean false"`

since if you call `casecmp` on an array it will return an undefined method error. If that's the case, you can continue to call `include?` to see if it matches.

```
if expected_value.include? "DataType_Boolean"
  #   Check that the actual value should be either true or false.
  if expected_value.include?("true") || expected_value.include?("false")
    result = "Passed"
  end
end
```

If the above assumption is true, your second if statement will never return true because of the inclusion of the extra parts of the string.

Comment: This is also not working. DataType_Boolean is value stored in data ase.

Comment: I am using postgresql. DataType_Boolean  stored in expected_value(text) column

Comment: Please include the actual output of `expected_value` in your question as well as the rest of the method where the conditional is running.